# Create a GWT RPC Service

Tags: gwt, service, server-side, rpc

I’m trying to create a backend for a homepage with `GWT`. I created a `Google Web Application` in `Eclipse` without sample code and now I would like to add the service, but the developer Google guide doesn’t help me. I’m not sure, where to add the interface and how it exactly works.

If I understand the google documentation correctly, I have to add a `module` and an `entry point class`, is that correct? It would be great if you could give me some tips and help how to create a rpc service.

Comment: The tutorial based on `StockWatcher` is a great start ! https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/gettingstarted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a new GWT project in the Eclipse "New Project" wizard, with "Generate project sample code" checked, it will include a fully functioning RPC service with a sample method, which you can then adapt or copy according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Out of memory, don't have eclipse in front of me.
First do create a test project with generated testcode, you can delete it afterward.
Yes you will have to add a module.
Create in client the two interfaces for the async calls, inherit it on server side.
Hope I understood your question right.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what would help you the most. Google developer guide was enough for me (at least when I started using it on version 1.6) to create RPC services for my GWT application.

**General APP**

Module: is the `.gwt.xml` file. Yes, you'll need it. The GWT compiler will find it automagically and try to compile all the GWT code (the `<source>` element will tell which subpackage contains Java code that will be converted to JS). It will tell also which class implements the EntryPoint interface. The onModuleLoad will be the code executed when javascript runs in the client page.

**RPC**

Well, you should first try UI things and only then, when you're confident enough, try the server thing. Anyway the scheme is:

```
interface MyService extends RemoteService {
 List<String> doSomething(String sample, int other);
}

@RemoteServiceRelativePath("../path/to/servlet") // see later
intercace MyServiceAsync {
 void doSomething(String sample, int other, AsyncCallback<List<String>> callback);
}
```

These are the interfaces. Later is the async one. That's what you'll use from client side. Always calling and passing an implementation of AsyncCallback which will receive (sometime later, you don't know when) the result.

First interface is the syncrhonous one. That is what you need to implement on server. You must inherit from RemoteServiceServlet class (it is an implementation of servlet that already does all the values handling), and implement your interface. GWT code does the rest (almost).

```
public class ServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements MyService
{
 // implement the method normally
}
```

From client you'll need to create the service proxy:

```
private static MyServiceAsync MY_SERVICE = GWT.create(MyService.class);
```

Yes. I know it's weird how GWT knows MyserviceAsync and MyService work together. Don't worry about that. It works :)

Just use the service like this:

```
MY_SERVICE.doSomething("value", 111, new AsyncCallback<List<String>>() {
   // note that this code executes some time in the future when response from server is back
   public void onSuccess(List<String> result) {
      Window.alert("Server answered with " + result.size() + " elements!");
   }
   public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
      Window.alert("Server failed: " + t.getMessage());
   }
}
```

**Path to server**

You'll have to configure your app to make that servlet implementation listen to URL indicated in @RemoteServiceRelativePath. That's the way client knows where to make the request, and the server knows which servlet attends that request. I'd suggest using:

`../my-service.gwt` as relative path (GWT module gets published in `<ROOT>/module_name`

and

configuring your web app to use the servlet for `/my-service.gwt`

But it's entirely upon your preferences :)

Anyway I think Google tutorials are the best. So please copy&paste. Try&modify until you get to understand the whole thing.